# How to have two progress bars running at the same time on screen in bash

Tags: bash

I have a piece of code for a progress bar just for looks. How can I have two progress bars displayed and loading at separate speeds on the screen in bash? This is the code I have for the first progress bar:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne '[###                   (15%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '[########              (42%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '[#############         (66%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '[####################] (100%)\r'
sleep 1
echo '\n'
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution; could probably do with a better calculation of the bar:

```
#!/bin/bash

pgbar(){
    progress1=$1
    progress2=$2
    if [ $progress1 -lt 25 ] ; then
        bar1='[###           (15%)'
    elif [ $progress1 -lt 50 ] ; then
        bar1='[######        (42%)'
    elif [ $progress1 -lt 99 ] ; then
        bar1='[#########      66%)'
    else
        bar1='[#############](100%)'
    fi
    if [ $progress2 -lt 25 ] ; then
        bar2='[###           (15%)'
    elif [ $progress2 -lt 50 ] ; then
        bar2='[######        (42%)'
    elif [ $progress2 -lt 99 ] ; then
        bar2='[#########      66%)'
    else
        bar2='[#############](100%)'
    fi
    echo -ne "$bar1" "$bar2" "\r"
}

pgbar 15 15
sleep 1
pgbar 15 50
sleep 1
pgbar 15 75
sleep 1
pgbar 55 75
sleep 1
pgbar 85 75
sleep 1
pgbar 100 75
sleep 1
pgbar 100 100
sleep 1
echo ''
```

Replace the `echo -ne "$bar1" "$bar2" "\r"` with

```
echo  "$bar1"  
echo  "$bar2" 
tput cuu1
tput cuu1
```

if you want the bars below each other.

Comment: this is perfect! but if i wanted to add a new line to space them what would i edit? its usally "echo" but it seems you used an alternitive

Comment: Just put an echo between the to bars and an extra line-up (`tput cuu1`) like this: `echo  "$bar1"; echo ""; echo  "$bar2"; tput cuu1;tput cuu1;tput cuu1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne '[###                   (15%)\n'
sleep 1
echo -ne '[********              (42%)\r'
tput cuu 1
sleep 1
echo -ne '[#############         (66%)\n'
sleep 1
echo -ne '[******************    (90%)\r'
tput cuu 1
sleep 1
echo -ne '[####################] (100%)\n'
sleep 1
echo -ne '[********************] (100%)\r'
echo -e '\n'
```

For more elaborate control, try ncurses library.